# verbatim-environment inside group implies unwanted paragraph-break. Why? How to avoid?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, verbatim, grouping

When I wrap a verbatim-environment into an additional group, a new paragraph will be started after that group.
(In the example below, `\parindent`-glue is inserted before the YYY when `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` are there.)

Why? How can this be avoided?

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=2cm

\begin{document}

XXX\begin{verbatim}
\LaTeX
\LaTeX
\LaTeX
\end{verbatim}
YYY

\noindent\null\hrulefill\null

XXX\begingroup\begin{verbatim}
\LaTeX
\LaTeX
\LaTeX
\end{verbatim}
\endgroup YYY

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of pdf that results from compiling the example]

Comment: While the `\parindent` is not there in the first case, there is, it would seem, a `\par` of some sort.  Just set `\parskip=5ex`, for example, to see where the paragraphs are inserted.  That is to say, `\endgroup\noindent` would appear to give the same result as the 1st case, regardless of `\parskip` and `\parindent`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes  In the article-class the verbatim-environment delivers the verbatimized-text as a `\trivlist`. This implies: In case the verbatim-environment itself is not the begin of a new paragraph, there is vertical `\topsep`-glue at the top and at the bottom of the verbatimized text. In case the verbatim-environment itself is the begin of a new paragraph, there is vertical `\topsep`-glue and vertical `\partopsep`-glue at the top and at the bottom of the verbatimized text.

Comment: This looks like an [XY-question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/179195). Why are you using the group to begin with? If it is for setting a different font size, then there are better methods.

Comment: @egreg I'm about to write an environment which does read its body under verbatim-catcode-régime and write it to .aux-file, wrapped into another environment which also does read its body under verbatim-catcode-régime for defining a macro where that verbatimized-read body is wrapped into a group/a local scope and into `\scantokens`.  Some sort of `\label`-`\ref`-thingie for saving arbitrary snippets of code where the `\label`-part is done by an environment whose argument holds the label name and whose body contains the snippet of code which might as well form a verbatim-environment...

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this by realizing the surrounding local scope by means of an environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=2cm

\newenvironment{localscope}{}{}

\begin{document}

XXX\begin{verbatim}
\LaTeX
\LaTeX
\LaTeX
\end{verbatim}
YYY

\noindent\null\hrulefill\null

XXX\begingroup\begin{verbatim}
\LaTeX
\LaTeX
\LaTeX
\end{verbatim}
\endgroup YYY

\noindent\null\hrulefill\null

XXX\begin{localscope}%
\begin{verbatim}
\LaTeX
\LaTeX
\LaTeX
\end{verbatim}
\end{localscope}YYY

\end{document}
```

[image]